# Numpy's loadtxt(): OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to load a matrix from a file using `numpy`. When I use any `dtype` other than `float` I get this error:

`OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

The code: 
`X = np.loadtxt(feats_file_path, delimiter=' ', dtype=np.int64 )`

The problem is that my matrix has only integers and I can't use a `float` because the first column in the matrix are integer "keys" that refer to node ids. When I use a `float`, numpy "rounds" the integer id into something like 32423e^10, and I don't want this behavior.

So my questions:

1. How to solve the OverflowError?
2. If it's not possible to solve, then how could I prevent numpy from doing that to the ids?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a compound dtype, with a separate type per column.  Or you can use `np.genfromtxt` without specifying any dtype, and it will be determined automatically, per each column, which may give you what you need with less effort (but perhaps slightly less performance and less error checking too).

Comment: this didn't solve the problem, because it used a float for the first column, which is the one that I don't want it to use floats for.

Answer (score 0):

Your number looks like it would fit in the `uint64_t` type, which is available if you have C99.

Comment: I couldn't find `numpy.uint64_t`. There's only `uint64`

Comment: numpy calls an unsigned 64-bit int `uint64`, C/C++ calls it `uint64_t`. They represent the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If the first column is an ID then you likely won't be doing any maths with it. You might even want it to preserve any leading zeroes in the ID. Thus, a string might be a better data type than an integer.

You can create a structured array which contains composite data types. Below I create an array of records, where each record contains space for a 10-character length string and two 32-bit integers.

```
>>> arr = numpy.loadtxt(b"""01 24 54
                            02 17 968
                            03 36 23""".split(b"\n"), 
                        dtype=[("id", "a10"),("values", "2i4")])
>>> arr
array([(b'01', [24, 54]), (b'02', [17, 968]), (b'03', [36, 23])], 
      dtype=[('id', 'S10'), ('values', '<i4', (2,))])
>>> arr["id"]
array([b'01', b'02', b'03'], 
      dtype='|S10')
>>> arr["values"]
array([[ 24,  54],
       [ 17, 968],
       [ 36,  23]], dtype=int32)
>>> arr[0]
(b'01', [24, 54])
>>> arr["values"] += 1
>>> arr
array([(b'01', [25, 55]), (b'02', [18, 969]), (b'03', [37, 24])], 
      dtype=[('id', 'S10'), ('values', '<i4', (2,))])
```

Here `dtype` is a list of tuples, the first element of each tuple being the field name and the second element being the data type. `"a10"` means a string of 10 characters. Find how many characters your longest ID has replace 10 with the appropriate amount. `2i4` means two columns of `i4` which is a 32-bit (4-bytes) integer. Change `i` to `f` if you need floats. If you need more precision you can increase 4 to 8 for a 64-bit data-type.